# 9V Vin powered Mega - 3V instead of 5V

Tags: arduino-mega, power, usb, voltage-level

I'm experiencing an issue with an Arduino Mega 2560 :
I powered the board through the Vin using a +24 --> 9V voltage regulator. When I power the board and measure the 5V output from the board, the voltage quickly drops from 5 to ~3V within seconds.

However, while powering with USB, the 5V output from the board gives us a clear 4.8V.

I have checked the 9V Voltage regulator (connected to the Vin), and it has a +24V input which remains stable (as should the 9V).

Any thoughts ?

Comment: How much current are you drawing from the regulator? In other words, what is connected to the regulator (if any) other than the Mega? Also, what is powered by the Mega?

Comment: Much more essential question is what `24V -> 9V` voltage regulator. Even 100mA means 1.5Watts turned into the heat on it if it's simple 7809 linear voltage regulator.

Comment: And what are the specs, esp. max output current, of the 24v - 9v regulator?

Comment: Roberto Lo Giacco > The Arduino board is the only component connected to the 9V regulator. I measured only 2mA from the +9V to the Vin. The mega powers two Leds, 1 TFT (1,8"), and 1 SD card reader.

Comment: KIIV > The Voltage regulator is made using a LM7809C. Two capacitors are used both from input to ground and from output to ground (as specified in the spec).
JRobert > The voltage regulator is designed to handle up to 1A.

Comment: Well, "designed to handle up to 1A" - yes and no. Yes if you have huge heat-sink on it at this voltage drop. So if you can carry it's safe operating area, it can deliver 1A (with 15Watts of power dissipation `P = (24V - 9V) * 1A` ).

Comment: All right, thank you. 
I noticed that after 20" or so, the heatsink becomes very hot (burning when touching), and this is the time when the voltage drops. I think there is some sort of overheating issue (although only 2mA are running through the 9V connector).

Comment: Power consumption about 2mA is highly unlikely as ATMega2560's consumption should be about 1mA per 1MHz so at least 16mA and add another for voltage regulator, LCD, LEDs...

Answer (score 1):

So, according to the comments the main problem should be a thermal protection in `LM7809C` regulator.

The voltage drop between regulator's input and output is about `15 Volts` and even with current consumption about `150mA` it means `2.25W` of power dissipation on it.

For such a big difference between input and output voltage switching regulator is recommended. (Or 9V power supply instead of 24V)

And it is not possible to have `2mA` current consumption. I've just measured power consumption of bare `Arduino Mega 2560` and it is `81mA` through barrel jack input (`9V`) without anything on it. Not even blinking Led. So if you've measured for example `0.2A` it's not `2mA` but `200mA`

Comment: I cannot change the power supply as it is powering another device (24V).
I will have a look at the switching regulators, ty.

However, how can the device not work with ~1% of its maximal current ? Could this be an issue related to the capacitors ? The manual I used gives a circuit at the page 18 : http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0e1f/0900766b80e1f8e6.pdf

Comment: Use DC-DC converter then. There are loads of them at ebay or so. And it's not possible to have only 2mA consuption not even with bare arduino board.

Comment: Thank you KIIV. 
It seems like the voltage regulator was the cause of this issue, since providing it a +12V (instead of +24V) has given us a good and steady +9V output (connected to the Arduino Vin). I think this was an overheating problem.
We've bought another DC-DC regulator as adviced to prevent this issue.

Comment: @EtienneP. Well, then you can mark it as a solution.

Comment: "how can the device not work with ~1% of its maximal current" because your measurement is wrong, and because even with a correct current measurement, the limit being hit is the power one, where the huge voltage drop you are asking it to regulate across is a multiplier.